# ASP.NET Charting Value Labels

Tags: c#, label, asp.net-charts

I'm using the ASP.NET Charting Toolkit (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) and am wondering if there is a way to turn the labeling of the stacked chart to on. As a default, when I plot my data using the stacked chart, the values for each of the series do not show. I am hoping there is a property (that I don't know of) which can allow me to view the values for each of the series when the chart is rendered.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the property that needs to be modified:

in asp:Series you set a property called IsValueShownAsLabel to true.